# How to send Hashmap with value with Retrofit

Tags: android, callback, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

I'm trying to send to API through POST an HashMap and an API KEY but I can't, because I need to send it like I do a @Field("something").
So what i want is @FieldMap("meta")

Example how i use Field:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api")
Call<CallBackMethod> save(@Query("apikey") String api_key,
                          @Field("something") String test);
```

How I currently use FieldMap, but the field map doesn't get send because the API is expecting an Array with a name "meta", so I get an error response from server Metadata does not exist in POST. THE API WORKS.
But I need to send it an Array with keys and values, that is a Hashmap in Java.

I'm calling this API something like this:

```
  Map<String, String> meta = new HashMap<>();
        meta.put("user_id", user_id);
        final Api apiService = ApiClient.getAPI().create(Api.class);
        Call<OtherMethod> call = apiService.getOtherMethod(API_KEY, meta);
  call.enqueue(new Callback<OtherMethod>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OtherMethod> call, Response<OtherMethod> response) {
            Log.d("Response Raw", response.raw() + "");
            Log.d("Response Raw", response.isSuccessful() + "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OtherMethod> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("E: t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Other class where the methods are:

```
   @FromUrlEncoded
        @POST("/api")
        Call<OtherMethod> getOtherMethod(@Query("apikey") String api_key,
                                              @FieldMap Map<String, String> meta);
```

**EDIT 1:**

After some messing around, I managed to get meta to be accepted, but now i have problems with encoding.
Current API:

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api")
    Call<CallBackMethod> getSomething(@Query("apikey") String api_key,
                                  @FieldMap HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> meta);
```

This is what it sends:

```
D/OkHttp: meta=%7Buser_id%3D431%7D
```

I tried with encoding=true and false both the same result.
This is what it should send

`meta={user_id=431}`
Does anybody have any idea how to disable encoding?

**EDIT 2:**
I changed the API so i send the @BODY and then json and it works. If anyone has solution for top problem i'll give credit too you.

Comment: what's the issue with `@FieldMap` ?

Comment: `@FieldMap` should work if your server expects a `Map` value.

Comment: The issue is that i can't set the name of FieldMap like I can in Field. The server expects the array with name meta, but i can't set the name to meta. If i send it like a  Field then it isn't an Map it is a String.

Comment: I found out it is a problem in encoding, this is the request it sends, tried encoding true and false:
`meta=%7Buser_id%3D401%7D`

Comment: Did you find the solution to give a key value for the Map ?

Answer (score 6):

HashMap with retrofit:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> RegisterUser(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params);


 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("userName", edt_uname.getText().toString());
        params.put("userEmail", edt_email.getText().toString());


ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getLogin().create(ApiInterface.class);
apiService.RegisterUser(params))


public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getLogin() {

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(GlobalConfig.Main_Url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have to give an Api key with the fieldmap?

Comment: params.put("apikey", yourkey);

Comment: Doesn't work because there has to be something like this, because if not i get an error that apikey isn't set:


`(@Query("apikey") String api_key,
                              @FieldMap Map<String, String> meta);`

Comment: Yeah, but the project is pretty big, I can only send you the pieces of code if that is okey? I can send you the php code of api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118895/discussion-between-winterchilly-and-viramp).

Answer (score 2):

**Data Fields**

If you want to send multiple data fields use `@FieldMap Map<String, String>`

**Query Parameters**

If you want to add multiple query parameters use `@QueryMap Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

try to query map function in retrofit api in GET method using hashmap.

```
 @GET("API-METHOD-NMAE")
 fun get_your_method_name(@QueryMap params: Map<String, String>): Call<Your_Class_Name>
```

And use gradle this one for latest one,

```
// retrofit
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Hope this works fine!

Answer (score -3):

Use below code spinnet:

```
public void makeStringReq_withparam(int PostType, String url, final Map<String, String> params1) {
   RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(PostType,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.putAll(params1);
                return params;
            }

        };


        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context1);
        mRequestQueue.add(strReq);

    }
```

Comment: This is with Volley and is not answering the question.